# ExecutorService timeout is not working as expected

Tags: java

The timeout should happen after one second, but it's not happening that way.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    int workerId;

    public Worker(int workerId) {
        super();
        this.workerId = workerId;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(workerId+"Worker Started ....");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(workerId+"Worker finishes.....");
    }
}

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
            executorService.submit(new Worker(i));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout Happen .....");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: What you expect to happen in `executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`? Which part of documentation makes you think that this code should behave the way you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
try {
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Timeout Happen .....");
}
```

doesn't do what you expect it to do.

> Throws:
>       InterruptedException - if interrupted while waiting

from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). Your code doesn't terminate within the second and the `InterruptedException` will only be thrown, if the thread was interrupted, while the code is waiting for the executorService to terminate. The correct wait to test whether the `executorService` actually terminated would be

```
try {
    if(executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        System.out.println("Terminated correctly");
    else
        System.out.println("Termination failed");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And `executorService.shutdown()` waits for running threads to terminate. So your code will wait the entire 20 seconds, until the submitted runnable terminates and won't accept or start any new `Runnables` in the meantime. If you want to terminate the `Thread` in a less gracefull way, you'll have to use `executorService.shutdownNow()`, which will interrupt running Threads.

Comment: I agree on your answer but how would I interrupt the running thread

Comment: `executorService.shutdownNow()` does that. It prevents the service from accepting any further runnables and usually interrupts all running Threrads.

Comment: You should try shutdownNow(). This prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks.

Comment: does executorService.shutdownNow() is a good idea or else We should always interrupt thru Future Object

Comment: Terminating through `future.cancle(true)` will only terminate the task, to which the Future-Object belongs. `executorService.shutdownNow()` will terminate **all** tasks that are running inside the `executorService`. But both work via interrupting the running Thread. So in your case there won't be much of a difference between calling one and calling the other, execpt that the approach via `Future` will keep the `executorService` running. Which one to choose rather depends on your requirements than anything else.

Comment: Thanks !! it's answer my question